# Sublime Text 2 - remove duplicated words in a list of words

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, duplicates, words

Is there anyway to remove duplicates in a list of words like this?

```
Hey
Hello
Hey
Hey
Jhon
Mark
Salcaz
```

i'm on macosx and each word is on new line formatted 1 word per line

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl` `⌘` `G`? It selects all occurrences of a given selection. If you start with an empty selection on Hey, it should respect word boundaries.

Comment: put this as an answer is actually very good tip man ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl` `⌘` `G` selects all occurrences of a pattern in the current file on a Mac in Sublime Text 2. So, in your example, dropping your cursor on any instance of `Hey` (not explicitly highlighting it) and invoking `Ctrl` `⌘` `G` will select every instance of `Hey` in your file. You can then delete all of them in one go and re-add a single instance.

A few things to note on `Ctrl` `⌘` `G` that might save you some headaches in the future. By default, it is case-insensitive. You can change this by invoking the global find and replace tool with `⇧` `⌘` `F` and toggling the case-sensitivity button. It should respect whichever option you leave it on for all subsequent searches.

Also, if you were to actually highlight an occurrence of `Hey` in your file and invoke `Ctrl` `⌘` `G`, it would pattern match *any* sequence of characters containing those letters in that order — e.g., if `they` were in your file, the `hey` in it would be selected.

Answer (score 14):

I see that I'm too late, but it's worth mentioning that sublime have command "Permute lines - Unique", which deletes duplicates from selected lines. Works like a charm, and there are answer on superuser about shortcuts: [hotkey to remove duplicate lines in sublime](https://superuser.com/questions/561355/hotkey-to-remove-duplicate-lines-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 8):

If you want a faster method, just select the whole text or list and go to `Edit - Permute Lines - Unique`. This will sort lines alphabetically and remove duplicated entries.

Another method is to sort your list alphabetically and search for duplicates manually.

---

See more details and live examples here:

http://html-tuts.com/remove-duplicate-lines-using-sublime-text/

Answer (score 2):

You can select multiple regions of text and edit them all at once.  On OS X highlight the desired word and press `Cmd+D` to select and go to the next occurrence or `Cmd+K+D` to skip and go to the next occurrence.

[Sublime Text selections](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection)

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
Edit -> Sort Lines (F9)
Edit -> Permute Lines -> Unique
```